# Low speed of CPU after windows update

Tags: windows-10, cpu, windows-10-v1607, cpu-speed

Problem: **CPU speed** after Windows 10 update don't rise up higer than **0.98 GHz**.

Windows 10 Version 1607 (OS Build 14393.51)

Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3537U CPU @ 2.00GHz

Notebook: Asus K56CB

[image: Power Options]

[image: Power Options]

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Which of the many Windows 10 updates, do you believe, is to blame for this behavior?

Comment: @Ramhound Latest [link](https://s14.postimg.org/uragf54rl/2016_08_23_16_43_02.png).

Comment: whats your system temp, are you on AC, and what program are you using to stress the CPU?

Comment: @FrankThomas Temperature is normal. Yes, on AC. PerfomanceTest 9.0

Comment: have you tried Prime95 for stress, and CoreTemp or Speccy for checking your current clock modifier in realtime (and resultant frequency)? you may be getting an average amortized over the runtime of the test.

Comment: reinstall the intel chipset drivers

Comment: Exactly where did you see that it was running at only 0.98 GHz? You haven't showed us any pictures where you received that information.

Comment: @DrZoo I use HWiNFO and Task Manager for current CPU info. I can't show because of low reputation (max 2 pics in main post).

Comment: @magicandre1981 thx a lot! It helps. You can rewrite this as answer :) But I still have some questions. Is it normal [to have 4 drivers](https://s4.postimg.org/mpv0nc04d/2016_08_24_00_55_26.png)?

Comment: @FrankThomas thanks for advise to try Prime95. My PerfomanceTest can't overstep 1.9 GHz... Prime95 easily force CPU to 2.75-78. But there still no Turbo (3.1 GHz). Why so?) (I know that Turbo mode is time limited, but it had not turned on at all)

Comment: @FrankThomas What does it mean [Turbo Locked](https://s14.postimg.org/mkrn8z735/2016_08_24_01_29_44.png)?

Comment: you have 2 CPU cores + hyperthreading, so you see cores in the device manager

Comment: the [Locked] tag on the Turbo, indicates that the clock modifier for turbo mode cannot be changed (overclocked).  As for why it won't use the full turbo speed, I'd recommend you monitor your temp and voltages. The chip should kick into turbo at times when it would be beneficial to a running thread, and all the environmental variables are within tight specifications, so as to avoid damaging the chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reinstall all chipset drivers ([Intel Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework driver](http://www.station-drivers.com/index.php?option=com_remository&Itemid=352&func=fileinfo&id=2316&lang=fr)), this driver is responsible for the power management of the cpu. During upgrade the driver was not correctly reinstalled.